# Install and deploy on EC2 with Apache/passenger app using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, amazon-ec2, capistrano, passenger

Anybody knows (A-Z)step by step popular instructions/guidance/tutorial/blog to install and deploy rails 3 app with Mysql DB on Amazon EC2 with capistrano including up setting up Apache and Phusion Passanger servers?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Linode has a few tutorials.  For example, this seem pretty useful.

http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid